# How to trigger events on google map with custom buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is [my demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duc_doan/8bwG2/269/), as you can see, I have 2 buttons named `Add Marker` and `Draw Line`, I want these buttons can work as google maps default buttons (like this photo).
[image]

I have read [google map api documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) and did what they said to trigger event `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click');` but my function didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, change the drawing mode when click the buttons and they are working as well

```
$( '#add-marker' ).on( 'click', function()
{
 drawingManager.setDrawingMode( google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER );
} );

$( '#draw-line' ).on( 'click', function()
{
 drawingManager.setDrawingMode( google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE );
} );
```